# Facebook access token expiration issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

In a case where i just wanted to fetch out feeds of a facebook page. If i use(i.e store locally on the app) the access token expires within a period of 60 days. Is there a solution where the access token can never expire. I read the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/) but this says we need to create a app access token for it. Is this is feasible solution or are there any approaches?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post with the app access token as the link says.

You don't have to create the app access token, instead its automatically generated when the app is created. You can check the access token for your app here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

But this will be changed IF you reset your app secret in future. Hope this helps.

Comment: So if in a case i create a app with my personal fb account and generate app access token. Use that to fetch out feeds for a URL like https://graph.facebook.com/CocoCola/feed?access_token="tokenvalue"since=0&limit=200 i can actually fetch out feeds of coca cola and use them in my app, does this violate any rights or privacy issues?

Comment: You are misguided, you are using the APP access token. If you know the access token of the coca-cola APP, yes you can do anything you want to do with coca-cola (at your own risk)

Comment: I used my own personal app access token to fetch out feeds of the coco cola page,My purpose is to just fetch out feeds, so can using my app access token expire for coca cola?